# Server Reboots after running sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

I setup an omnibus package gitlab-ce version 8.12.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 Server.  I ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and it worked fine the first time.  I then restored a backup from a different server which I upgraded from 8.0 to 8.12.7 because you can only restore from same version.  After doing the restore it worked fine.

My admin decided take down the old server and change the IP address of the one I recently setup to the old production servers IP address.  Thus the IP address is now different from the first time I ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

**NOTE: The first time I did this we simply pointed the same ip to a different FQDN**

Now after changing some parameters in `gitlab.rb` when I run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` It gets as far as:

`Starting Chef Client, version 12.12.15`

and the server reboots.

I've never seen this happen. Postfix is not set to the correct mail server yet, but that shouldn't reboot the server.  Has anybody come across this before?

Comment: I don't think that the gitlab chef recipes contain automatic reboots. Is this a physical server or a vm? What version of the kernel do you have and what video driver modules?  This sounds almost like a kernel panic. Have a look in the systemd logs (using journalctl)

Comment: The chef recipe definitely doesn't contain a reboot. I would be suprised if it had anything to do with gitlab.

Comment: It's a physical server and running 4.4.0-45-generic.  The video driver installed is ASPEED Graphics Family

Answer (score 0):

The server did not like its IP address being changed.  Our solution was to change the IP address back to the original one it was setup on.  We change the DNS to point to the new IP, and told all the users using SSH to delete the record for gitlab in the `known_hosts` file if they got the "Man in the Middle Attack" warning